# создание множества нотификаций в отдельном потоке

Tags: java, android, service, android-intent

всем здрям.

**Проблема такая:** на входе есть некий список объектов, который формируется в сервисе. Нужно при получении этого списка сделать уведомления по одному на каждую позицию (из этого же сервиса).

Нотификации создаю, кидаю туда интенты, но при нажатии на интент открывается нужная активити и берет какую то ересь из этого интента.

Где я не прав?

```
  private void sendNotificationEarchNewItems(List<Map<String, Object>> newIrems) {

    final List<Map<String, Object>> locList = newIrems;

    final Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (Map map : locList) {               
                final Context context = getApplicationContext();
                final String idd = map.get("_id").toString();

                final int NOTIF_ID = Integer.parseInt(idd.substring(0, 6));
                final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ItemActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("_id", idd);
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(thisContext, 0, intent, 0);

                final Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) 
                        .setContentTitle(map.get("title").toString())
                        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                        .build();

                notificationManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, notification);



                final RemoteViews contentView = notification.contentView;
                final int iconId = android.R.id.icon;                    
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(map.get("mainImage").toString()).into(contentView, iconId, NOTIF_ID, notification);
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: еще раз проанализировал отладчиком. "_ид", идущий в интент перезаписывается при каждом создании новой нотификации. значит надо передать в интент весь список и айди уведомления для сопоставления. но как отловить нажатие на уведомление?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У пендингинтента поставил одинаковые реквест коды. Вот с такой правкой все заработало.

```
 PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(thisContext, NOTIF_ID , intent, 0);
```